# CRM2011 check if notes on custom form contains data via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

Hi peeps on stackoverflow,

Product: CRM2011, should be latest roll-up

I'm currently trying to get the following to Work: 
- A custom CRM form has been made. This form contain the 'Notes' tab. I would like to dynamically 'expand' this IF and only IF the 'Notes' tab contains notes data. I'm trying to do this through JavaScript loaded into 'Form Libraries'. I can easily 'expand' the notes field but I'm having serious trouble determining if the 'Notes' tab contains notes data.

I can understand that accessing the 'notes' data through the DOM is not a good idea so I've tried through XRM. Looked through https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334351(v=crm.5).aspx to see my options. But I can't seem to get to one where I can access 'notes' and base the expansion of the notes field on if there is data or not in 'notes'.

Is this possible? I'm looking forward to hear from you and thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Notes are their own entity type, entity logical name is Annotation, that is why you won't find the notes data within Xrm.Page.  I'm making some assumptions here, but if you've set up this custom entity to follow standard conventions, any notes on that record will be separate Annotation records with a reference to the custom entity record. using the sdk.jquery.js script provided with the SDK you can do a query on Annotation records that reference the record you are currently on.  That would be a supported way to determine if the record has notes.  Using the OrganizationData.svc endpoint you would have an OData query that looks something like this

```
AnnotationSet?$filter=ObjectId/Id eq guid'34d19133-c0ec-e311-b39c-6c3be5bd2b14'
```

The guid value there would be the guid of the record you are currently on, which if you haven't already acquired within your script, you can get it pretty easily with something like this

```
window.parent.Xrm.Page.data.entity.getId().substring(1, 37)
```

or without the `window.parent` prefixing it

Comment: Hi AK3800 thank you very much for your answer. Highly appreciated. Unfortunately I cannot verify the suggestion as I'm not allowed to spend more hours on the challenge. Your findings though match what I have been able to conclude and I therefore think that this would indeed solve it.